# Чтение зашифрованного при помощи gpg -c файла в golang

Tags: linux, golang, gpg

У меня есть файл test.txt который я зашифровал при помощи gpg -c text.txt
Можно ли в программе на языке go открыть такой файл и прочитать содержимое (пароль, конечно, мне известен)

Comment: Эм, а google golang gpg не помогает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы зашифровали `gpg -c`, то в файле `text.txt.gpg` находится binary message. Его можно расшифровать средствами пакета `github.com/ProtonMail/gopenpgp/v2/`:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/ProtonMail/gopenpgp/v2/armor"
    "github.com/ProtonMail/gopenpgp/v2/constants"
    "github.com/ProtonMail/gopenpgp/v2/helper"
)

func main() {
    gpgfile := "text.txt.gpg"
    data := Must(io.ReadAll(Must(os.Open(gpgfile))))
    pwd := "123"

    armored := Must(armor.ArmorWithType(data, constants.PGPMessageHeader))
    txt := Must(helper.DecryptMessageWithPassword([]byte(pwd), armored))
    fmt.Println(txt)
}

func Must[T any](val T, err error) T {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    return val
}
```

Результат работы программы:

```
Hello, world!
```

Это в точности содержимое файла `text.txt`